# how do I test for a unique string with multiple possibilities?

Tags: conditionals, strings, pdfstrcmp

I'm writing a macro that takes a string and it returns an `href` based on that string. The string could have 150 different values. My question is how to write this in an efficient way. Using `pdflatex`.

Here's what I've got right now, shortened to two conditions for explanation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{%
   \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{aaa}=0%
      \href{example.com/aaa}{my aaa link}
   \fi
   \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{bbb}=0%
      \href{example.com/bbb}{my bbb link}
   \fi
}
\begin{document}
Here is \myref{aaa}.
\end{document}
```

But of course once I get a success (`#1=aaa`, say), I'm still testing the other 149 conditions for no reason. How to code this efficiently?

Comment: Are all of the outcomes of the form `\href{example.com/<string>}{my <string> link}`?

Comment: Ah, I simplified too much. It will actually take two args. first arg goes in the link address, the second provides the link text. Like \href{example.com/aaa}{The Title of the AAA Document} (link text will have completely different text on each invocation of the macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would e.g. create command names:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{aaa@link}{\href{example.com/aaa}{my aaa link}}
\@namedef{bbb@link}{\href{example.com/bbb}{my bbb link}}

\newcommand{\myref}[1]{%
 \csname #1@link\endcsname}

\begin{document}
Here is \myref{aaa}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

let biber do the searching for you:

assuming there is a file `test.bib` with

```
@online{tex,
  note={my aaa text},
  url={tex.stackexchange.com}
}

@online{google,
  note={my bbb text},
  url={www.google.com}
}
```

then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\href{#1}{\printfield{note}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myref}{}{\usebibmacro{url}}{}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Here is \myref{tex}

\myref{google}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xparse`:

```latex
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newref}{mmm}
 {% #1 = key, #2 = URL, #3 = description, #4 = options for \href
  \prop_gput:Nnx \g_tima_sites_prop { #1 @ url } { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_tima_sites_prop { #1 @ desc } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myref}{m}
 {% #1 = key
  \tima_href:xx
   { \prop_item:Nn \g_tima_sites_prop {#1 @ url } }
   { \prop_item:Nn \g_tima_sites_prop {#1 @ desc } }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_tima_sites_prop
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tima_href:nn { \href{#1}{#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tima_href:nn { xx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newref{texworks}{http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/introtexworks}{\TeX works intro}
\newref{arara}{http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/introarara}{Arara intro}
\newref{tex.sx}{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{Nice site}

\begin{document}

\myref{texworks}

\myref{arara}

\myref{tex.sx}

\end{document}
```